# $_GET remove string(30) and making it to output what I want only?

Tags: php, get

I coded this script and when I search for a user it shows

> string(30) "result=2014-01-30 12:18:03&b=r"

the result=000000000 0000000&b=r is part of the api I'm using but the string(30) isn't and it outputs that too, how do I remove the string(30) and would I be able to replace the result text with something I choose?

Here's my script, you search a username and it outputs their last logged on date.

```
<html>
<h2> ----- </h2>
<?php
    if (!empty($_GET['userID'])) { //First check
        $url = 'http://api-testing.agame.com/php/getLastLog.php';
        $data = array('userID' => $_GET['userID']); //Then use the value

        // use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
        $options = array(
            'http' => array(
                'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
                'method'  => 'POST',
                'content' => http_build_query($data),
            ),
        );
        $context  = stream_context_create($options);
        $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

        var_dump($result);
    }
?>

<form action='' method='get'>
    <input type='text' name='userID' />
    <input type='submit' value='Search' />
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/var_dump) is **only for debugging**. Don't use it for anything else.

Comment: var_dump displays `type` and `value`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`parse_str()`](https://www.php.net/parse_str):

```
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
parse_str($result);
echo $result; // 2014-01-30 12:18:03
```

or

```
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
parse_str($result, $output);
echo $output['result']; // 2014-01-30 12:18:03
```

Comment: `parse_str($result)` will not do what you think it does. It will transform the keys into separate variables in the current scope, which is a bad idea anyway. You'll have to use the second parameter to define the `$params` array, like so: `parse_str($result, $params)` and only then you'll be able to access it as `$params['result']`.

Comment: [It would work](http://codepad.viper-7.com/tJfSTN). I just needed to fix my example.

Comment: `parse_str($result)` might overwrite any arbitrary variables in the current scope, so this is a **bad practice**. I'd use the second parameter to store the parsed values in an array.

Comment: Help me please, this is what I've done http://prntscr.com/2xj0dm I search or a user and it says Notice: Undefined variable: context in C:\xampp\htdocs\game\1\testlog.php on line 16

Comment: I've tried your new one and it says the same thing undefined line 16, but now it shows me the date of the user.

Answer (score 0):

look at [var_dump()][1]
[1]:https://www.php.net/var_dump

it is used for check the value and type of php variables(debugging purpose).

You have correct data in this line :

```
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

so just remove this line :

```
var_dump($result);
```